# how to bind the correct syntax for html in php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a variable in php which contains an input with a inclick event like this:

```
$SelectButton = '<input type="button" class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, "id1")" value="Select All and Copy" /><br>';
```

I use this php variable in a javascript to prepend it to a class like this:

```
$('.surroundpre', this).prepend('$SelectButton');
```

When I look into the source with my browser, I see this code which is created:

```
<input type="button" class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, " id1")"="" value="Select All and Copy">
```

As you can see, the is a **space** before **id1** and there is **"=""** before the value.
So there must be something wrong with the syntax but I cannot figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use single quotes within the `onclick` attribute and escape them. Try this:

```
$SelectButton = '<input type="button" class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, \\\'id1\\\')" value="Select All and Copy" /><br>';
```

Comment: I tried this but the button does not appear anymore now

Comment: That would appear to be a separate issue. Have you checked the PHP logs, or JS console for errors?

Comment: you are right, there is a syntax error which says: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: this is what is parsed and in this line is something wrong: $('.surroundpre', this).prepend('<input type="button" class="control-copytextarea" onclick="return fieldtoclipboard.copyfield(event, 'id1')" value="Select All and Copy" /><br>');

Comment: You also need to include a \ before the `'` in the output, check my updated answer.